# Collector returning singletonList if toList returned empty list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have quite a large stream pipeline and therefore would like to keep it clean. I have the following part of larger pipeline

```
Integer defaultInt;
//...
Stream<Integer> ints;
ints.filter(/* predicate_goes_here */).collect(toSingletonIfEmptyCollector);
```

Where `toSingletonIfEmptyCollector` is supposed to act the same as `Collectors.toList()` does if it returns non-emtpy list and `Collections.singletonList(defaultInt)` if `Collectors.toList()` returned empty.

Is there a shorter way to implement it (e.g. by composing standard collectors provided in JDK) rather then implementing all `Collector`'s method from scratch?

Comment: I assume you don't mutate the resulting List.

Comment: There are bunch of helper methods that maybe useful in `IntStream` over `Stream<Integer>`. **Note:** `IntStream` is a *primitive stream* (just a small tip)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) and perform an additional finisher operation on the built-in `toList()` collector that will return a singleton list in case there was no elements.

```
static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList(T defaultValue) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
              Collectors.toList(), 
              l -> l.isEmpty() ? Collections.singletonList(defaultValue) : l
           );
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(toList(5))); // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
System.out.println(Stream.empty().collect(toList(5))); // prints "[5]"
```

Comment: I'd rather name the custom collector with something more specific such as  `toListOrDefault` specially that it is static, would be afraid to cause confusion with `Collectors.toList`, specially if static imports are used.